# ActionScript 3: Conditional compilation on compiler or sdk version?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

Does the Flex compiler pass a version number that's accessible to conditional compilation? The problem I'm facing is I have some common code that may be used with SDK 10 or 11 and it uses JSON. I want to be able to not force 11 users to use the external JSON library as JSON functionality is in the 11 SDK.

I realize I can set my own compiler parameter, but I wanted to avoid that if possible, so users of the shared code don't need to remember to set this parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, no such thing, unfortunately. You may, however, account on version being a static variable declared on all framework components (it would make it a runtime check instead).

Comment: After much research because I didn't want to believe it was true, I sadly accept your answer.